# Case When Syntax Error and Function

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error, case, case-when

I am trying to group certain employees to a program by using a Case When function. However, I am getting a (missing operator) syntax error and cannot seem to find the issue.

```
SELECT i360.LOCALDAY, i360.SalesID, i360.ACDID, i360.Employee,     i360.Supervisor, i360.Manager, i360.Campaign, i360.Employee_Org, 



CASE
WHEN i360.Supervisor = "Bell, Barry"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Call, Jessica"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Carico, Nicole"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Casse, Jennifer"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Edwards, Billy"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Gregory, Angie"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Huffman, Wes"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Kelly, Jessica"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Lyall, Brandy"
THEN "Interior_Supervisors" 

WHEN i360.Supervisor = "Metcalfe, Cameron"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Miller, Stephanie"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Ruggles, John"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Shobe, Nathaniel"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Simms, Aaron"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Spruill, April"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Stanfield, Chad"
OR i360.Supervisor = "Woods, Edward" 

THEN "Core_Supervisors"

ELSE "Exterior_Supervisors"
END as Program,


FROM t_i360 AS i360 INNER JOIN t_cms AS cms ON    (cms.LOCALDAY=i360.LOCALDAY)    AND (cms.LOGID=i360.ACDID);
```

Comment: Access doesn't support `CASE ... WHEN`. Use `Switch` instead.

Comment: Additional note: hardcoding all these names into a query is not a good idea. The names and their roles should be read from a table or query.

Comment: Seems like an odd database design...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `in` and `switch`:

```
switch(i360.Supervisor in ("Bell, Barry", "Call, Jessica", "Carico, Nicole", . . .),
       "Interior_Supervisors",
       i360.Supervisor in ("Metcalfe, Cameron", "Miller, Stephanie", "Ruggles, John", . . . ),
      "Core_Supervisors",
      1=1,
      "Exterior_Supervisors"
     ) as Program,
```